# Express.js session - redirect error

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, frontend

I keep encountering this error when I execute my code which has the pseudocode listed below (To clarify, my code is based on the react-redux-universal-hot-example)

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
[2]     at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
[2]     at ServerResponse.header (/pathToUI/ui/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
[2]     at ServerResponse.location (/pathToUI/ui/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:835:8)
[2]     at ServerResponse.redirect (/pathToUI/ui/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:874:8)
[2]     at api.js:165:11
[2]     at Layer.handle     [as handle_request] (/pathToUI/ui/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[2]     at trim_prefix (/pathToUI/ui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
[2]     at /pathToUI/ui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
[2]     at Function.process_params (/pathToUI/ui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
[2]     at next (/pathToUI/ui/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10
```

I am trying to redirect the user to the homepage (/) and the user is at /home after having logged in.   Basically, the session is controlled by a timer in the express session.  When the time is up, I want to redirect the user to the homepage (the next time a request is made).

the following code would be in the [api.js file](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/api/api.js)

```
app.use( (req, res, next) => {

    if (req.session.user != undefined) {
        if(sessionNotOver) 
            Renew session
    }
    else if (sessionOver/ expired ) {
        console.log('expired session');
        res.status(403).end('SESSION EXPIRED');
        res.redirect('/');
        return;
        //req.session.destroy();
    } else {
        console.log('session has no user, but it is: ' + JSON.stringify(req.session));
    }
});
```

I am able to correctly keep track of the session, but I am having trouble redirecting the user to the homepage.  **What tips do you have for me to accomplish this?  Would it be better for me to put the redirect somewhere else (ie. in [server.js?](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/server.js))**

I have tried consulting multiple stackoverflow posts and I have also done a lot of Googling/ testing, but nothing seems to work.  I might be misunderstanding something though, so it would be nice if someone could clarify some things and / or give me some tips.  Thanks!

**EDIT**   So I tried changing the line as Shimon Brandsdorfer mentioned below, but my application still doesn't redirect, now it is just stuck on a loading screen which is another component that displays a loading gif until the other timer (in App.js) times out.

Comment: This error is because you are trying to send another response after `res.status(403).end('SESSION EXPIRED');`. You cannot send another response once you call `end()`. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086621/7096322

Comment: "I can't post the code for privacy reasons" your codes not special

Comment: @Darkrum I have updated the post with more details about the basic structure of the code.  If you can help me that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your error is self-explaining, you cannot send twice a HTTP response to the same request. once you did `res.status(403).end()` you actually have sent the response, and you cannot redirect afterwards.

So what you can do, is simply send the response just once.

```
res.redirect(403, '/');
```

Or:

```
res.status(403).location('/').end('sesssion expired');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I must have missed that line when I read the API.  I updated my post above with more details about how my web application is set up (basic structure is the example I mentioned).